# Is it possible to execute a code block for first looping, then a different code block for every loop after?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, block, execute

Is it possible to have one code block execute when the loop runs throught once, then every time after it run a different code block?

for example, I have:

```
while ($blank > 0) {
  echo "<td></td>";
  $blank--;
  $day_count++;
}
```

I would like to change it to this for the first time it runs:

```
  echo "<td class = 'left'></td>";
```

Then after the first loop through, go to this:

```
  echo "<td></td>";
```

Is that possible at all?

Comment: What are the values of `$blank` and `$day_count` before the loop?

Comment: $day_count always is equal to 0, however $blank can change based on the month. It's for my php calendar, and $blank is the number of days that precedes the current month, such as December 2014 has one blank day (first day of month is on monday)

Answer (score 2):

```
$firstrow = true;
while ($blank > 0) {
    if ($firstrow) {
       echo "<td class = 'left'></td>";
       $firstrow = false;
    } else {
      echo "<td></td>";
    }
  $blank--;
  $day_count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear from your question what "first time" means for you. But in principle, you should be able to create a variable that indicates whether this is the first time. For example, you can use `isset`:

```
while($blank>0) {
  if !isset($notTheFirstTime){
    ...
  }
  else {
  }
  $notTheFirstTime = 1
}
```

The first time you encounter this loop, the variable `$notTheFirstTime` does not yet exist, and the first block of code is run; once you've been through the loop once, the variable exists. That means this will only run once. On the other hand, if you want to do something "on the first pass through the loop, every time I encounter the loop" then I would recommend just putting the relevant code outside of the loop, rather than inside.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    //$blank = 3;
    //$day_count = 0; 

    for($i = $blank; $blank > 0; $blank--) {
        if($i == $blank)
            echo "<td class = 'left'></td>";
        else
            echo "<td></td>";
      $day_count++;
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
<td class = 'left'></td><td></td><td></td>
```

Comment: Where did the `while` loop go?

Comment: @putvande I changed it to a for loop so that it's cleaner and easier to read!

Comment: Use a for loop. Nicely done, I keep forgetting I can set variables to other variables inside there.

Comment: @Vince Jeah i thought this way it's easier to understand and for readability

Comment: This might be fine, but if subsequent code relies on `$blank` being 0 after the loop it might fail unpredictably.

Comment: @HoboSapiens updated it so that `$blank` is 0 after the loop if he needs it later (thanks for the hint)